# unresolved overload with bind and make_pair

Tags: c++, stl, boost-bind

I am trying to copy all of the keys of a `map` into another by using `std::for_each and boost::bind`.

I am getting compile error saying

```
 error: no matching function for call to 
 ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, boost::arg<1>&, boost::arg<1>&)’
```

Below my code.

```
 using namespace boost;
 map<string,int32_t> A;

 typedef map<string,string>  BType;
 BType B;

 std::for_each(A.begin(), A.end(), 
         bind(&BType::insert,&B,bind(&std::make_pair,_1,_1)));
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: try `std::make_pair<string,string>`

Comment: and `_1` in your case is `std::pair<string, int32_t>`, not just `string`

Comment: After changing `std::make_pair`, your `bind` call will create a nullary function object that tries to insert a function object into `B`.

Comment: write regular for loop first and then after getting it working convert it to `for_each`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key problem is that you can't take the address of an overload set: `std::make_pair` is a function template and you don't even state what instantiation(s) you are talking about. Likewise `std::map<K, V>::insert` is overloaded, e.g., with a version taking one element and a version taking a range.

Even if you could take the address of an overloaded function in some form, you actually don't really want to if you can help it! The reason is that calling through a function pointer or a member function pointer is a lot more expensive than calling an `inline` function and calls through function pointers are much harder to inline: the compiler has to proof that a particular [member] function pointer always refers to the same [member] function.

The solution to both problems is to give `bind()` a function object with a templated function call operator which simply delegates to the appropriate function. For example:

```
struct make_a_pair {
    template <typename T0, typename T1>
    std::pair<T0, T1> operator()(T0&& t0, T1&& t1) {
        return std::make_pair(std::forward<T0>(t0), std::forward<T1>(t1));
    }
};
```

When using C++03 you'd use `T0 const&` and `T1 const&` instead of `T0&&` and `T1&&` and you'd just pass the arguments instead of using `std::forward<>()`. In a C++11 setting you'd probably rather return a type using `decltype()`. A similar function object for inserting could look like this:

```
struct inserter {
    template <typename M, typename T>
    void operator()(M* map, T&& value) {
        map->insert(std::forward<T>(value));
    }
};
```

With these two function objects in place you could use your `bind()` expressions:

```
std::for_each(A.begin(), A.end(),
    boost::bind(inserter(), &B, boost::bind(make_a_pair(), _1, _1)));
```

Right now I can't quite test this easily but something along those lines should work, assuming pairs of `_1` and `_1` are what is desired. It seems, you really want to create a mapping from the key to the key in which case you'd need to appropriately project the keys of the original map, e.g., using another function object:

```
struct project1st {
    template <typename T0, typename T1>
    typename std::remove_const<T0>::type
    operator()(std::pair<T0, T1> const& p) const {
        return p.first;
    }
};
```

This function object removes a `const` from the first `T0` if there is any (if the pair is from a `std::map<K, V>` the pair will be of type `std::pair<K const, V>`) before returning the result. You'd replace each `_1` with a suitable `std::bind()` expression using this function object, i.e., with

```
boost::bind(project1st(), _1)
```

Comment: There is a remaining problem: for_each is also working on pairs... so `make_a_pair(), _1, _1` is called with two pairs of string/int...

Comment: @Johan: er, yes. To solve that it is necessary to project `_1` to the appropriate value. I'll update the answer, mentioning that part, too.